Trying to get custom OID using SNMP in LibreNMS
I'm trying to get a custom OID value into LibreNMS using SNMP.
I beleive I have been able to add the value into SNMP using the following within /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
extend  .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1 temp_hi_in  /bin/sh /home/test/test.sh
And this script contains:
#!/bin/bash
SENSOR=$1
SLAVE="/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-666a741f64ff/w1_slave"
OUTPUT=$(/bin/cat $SLAVE | /usr/bin/awk -F 't=' ' { printf $2 } ')
echo .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1
echo guage
echo $OUTPUT

As I can see the value when using:
snmpwalk -v3  -l auth -u {user} -a MD5 -A {MD5} localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1

As it returns this:
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.3.1.1.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110 = STRING: ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.3.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110 = STRING: ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1
guage
28562"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.3.1.3.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110 = INTEGER: 3
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.3.1.4.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110 = INTEGER: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.1 = STRING: ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.2 = STRING: "guage"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3 = STRING: "28562"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.1.0 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.2.1.2.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49 = STRING: "/bin/sh"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.2.1.3.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49 = STRING: "/home/hydromonitor/get_hi_in.sh"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.2.1.4.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.2.1.5.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49 = INTEGER: 5
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.2.1.6.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.2.1.7.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.2.1.20.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49 = INTEGER: 4
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.2.1.21.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.3.1.1.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49 = STRING: ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.3.1.2.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49 = STRING: ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1
guage
28562"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.3.1.3.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49 = INTEGER: 3
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.3.1.4.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49 = INTEGER: 0
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.4.1.2.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49.1 = STRING: ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.4.1.2.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49.2 = STRING: "guage"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.4.1.2.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49.3 = STRING: "28562"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.4.1.2.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49.1 = STRING: ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1"
Error: OID not increasing: iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.4.1.2.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49.3
 >= iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3.4.1.2.13.116.101.109.112.95.115.101.110.115.111.114.95.49.1

Where 28562 is the value I want to see in LibreNMS.
In LibreNMS I have added a custom OID and tried to get the value returned, but I get nothing displayed.
I have tried setting the OID in LibreNMS to a number of different values such as :
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1.4.1.2.10.116.101.109.112.95.104.105.95.105.110.3

But I get nothing (no value) returned within LibreNMS.
Any help would be appreciated.

I'll admit I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do. It looks like you have a temperature sensor, and you're just trying to get a single reading from it, is that right? Is all that output for snmpwalk expected, or do you just want it to return a Gauge32 representing 28562 as the value for the OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.7.1?

@TallChuck thanks for your reply. I'm trying to create a custom OID and add it to the SNMP response that is picked up by LibreNMS as a "custom OID". You are correct, I just want to pick up a guage returning that value in the custom OID, but despite LibreNMS getting all the values from the SNMP off the device, I can't get that custom OID value to show up. Thanks.

I'm not sure exactly how to do that with the tools you are using, but it looks like the problem is not with LibreNMS, it's with something in the setup of your agent. If you decode the OIDs from snmpwalk, you'll see that they include the string "temp_hi_in". I also think that extend is the wrong keyword to use, because it can only deal with string types, and it only runs the script once. You need something that can use Gauge32, and that will run the script every time it gets a request
